# What am I doing wrong? **JSON[27471:6916633] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed**

Tags: swiftui, reddit

when I run bellow code I get the following message in debug console:

**JSON[27471:6916633] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed**

and a blank screen in the simulator.

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I am brand new to **all** off this so please go easy on me.

```
import SwiftUI
        
        struct Response: Codable {
            var results: [Result]
        }
        
        struct Result: Codable {
            var id: String
            var title: String
            var subreddit: String
        }
        
        struct ContentView: View {
            @State var results = [Result]()
            
            var body: some View {
                List(results, id: \.id) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.subreddit)
                            .font(.headline)
                        
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: loadData)
            }
            
            func loadData() {
                guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/.json") else {
                    print("Invalid URL")
                    return
                }
                
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                    if let data = data {
                        if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.results = decodedResponse.results
                            }
                            return
                        }
                    }
                    
                    print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknow error")")
                }.resume()
            }
        }
        
        struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
```

Comment: The message is irrelevant, Rather than `try?` which means to ignore errors remove the question mark, wrap the line in a `do - catch` block and `print(error)`. DecodingErrors are very descriptive.

Comment: @vadian's advice is, of course, spot on. I'll also point out that if you visit the URL that you're getting data from, it looks nothing like the `Response` or `Result` structs that you've set up. So, you'll need to do some work to figure out how to model the data. I'd suggest using app.quicktype.io to generate some models for yourself.